# Extract Year from a character variable in redshift query editor

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a variable in my redshift table. Variable name is service_date and its a character variable. i want to get the year from this variable. i am using below code but it's not working.

```
extract(year from (cast(service_date as date))
```

Sample data of date-

```
17-Mar-10
2-Mar-10
19-Nov-10
19-Nov-10 etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it following way--

**From Timestamp**

```
 select DATE_PART_YEAR('2019-01-15 04:47:22');
 date_part_year
 -----------
       2019
(1 row)
```

**From Date**

```
 select  DATE_PART_YEAR('2019-01-15');

 date_part_year
 -----------
       2019
 (1 row)
```

But looking into your sample data, it could be understood easily that your data is in text format not in date format, hence it needs to be `casted first to the date`, then the `DATE_PART_FUNCTION` could be used.

```
select DATE_PART_YEAR(to_date('10-Nov-15','DD-Mon-YY'));
```

Here `to_date` function convert `text` to `date` and then extracts the Year.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: i am trying DATE_PART_YEAR(service_date ) and DATE_PART_YEAR('service_date ') both are not working.

Comment: It should work, add some sample data of `service_date` to your question. It will be easy to use that data for confirming your claim.

Comment: please find below.

17-Mar-10
2-Mar-10
19-Nov-10
19-Nov-10
5-Mar-10
5-Mar-10
5-Mar-10
5-Mar-10
5-Mar-10

Comment: those look like strings not date values, can you check the type of that column? is it date/timestamp? if they are strings then take a look https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html you can use that to convert your string to a date, then use date_part_year as described by Red Boy

Comment: Do it like this `select  DATE_PART_YEAR(to_date('10-Nov-15','DD-Mon-YY'));`

Comment: i tried this and it's working fine. DATE_PART_YEAR(to_date(serv_current_ts,'DD-Mon-YY')) 

Can you please let me know how to get the month?

Comment: Good to know that it worked for you, cheers! Will you mind accepting this as a correct answer? I think you could take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html where it explains all the possible `date part` options.